# Copy Range of Cells to a Word Document based on IDs from a different column

Tags: excel, vba

So we have this table we are using at the office. I changed the Column Name and Content for confidentiality purposes.

[image]

We're trying create a Word Document for each ID consisting of all the Name's and Surnames for that ID only from our Excel file.

i.e. A new Word Document is created for ID1. The contents are all the Names and Surnames only for that ID1 excluding the Column Name. Another Word Document will be created for the next ID available until all IDs have their own document,

So far this is what I got:

```
Sub test()

Dim copyRng As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set copyRng = Range("B2:C" & lastrow)

Range("B2:C" & copyRng.Rows.Count).Select
Selection.Copy
'Declare Word Variables
    Dim WrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim WrdDoc As Word.Document
'Create a new instance of Word
    Set WrdApp = New Word.Application
        WrdApp.Visible = True
        WrdApp.Activate
'Create a new Document in the Word Application
    Set WrdDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Add
        WrdDoc.Activate
        WrdDoc.Range(WrdDoc.Characters.Count - 1).Paste
End Sub
```

I can't seem to copy only the rows for a specific ID.
Can anyone suggest a better solution copy only the cells based on the IDs?

Answer (score 0):

I simplified my problem in the meantime.

First I select the cells I want to be copied over to a Word Document.

Then I run this code:

```
Selection.Copy
'Declare Word Variables
    Dim WrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim WrdDoc As Word.Document
'Create a new instance of Word
    Set WrdApp = New Word.Application
        WrdApp.Visible = True
        WrdApp.Activate
'Create a new Document in the Word Application
    Set WrdDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Add
        WrdDoc.Activate
        With WrdDoc.Range(WrdDoc.Characters.Count - 1).Characters.Last
        .PasteExcelTable False, True False
             With .Tables(1)
                  .AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
             End With
                  .InsertAfter Chr(1)
        End With
```

This way, I just have to highlight the cells I want to be copied over to Word and Run the Macro. The Macro will create a new Word Document for me.